# pwdChangedTime which is not allowed by any of the objectclasses defined in that entry in OpenDj LDAP

Tags: opendj

I installed a new LDAP server (OpenDJ 2.4.6). I am trying to enable the replication with reference of existing server. But I am getting the below issue.

I ran the replication command, existing server (1st server). Can you please help/suggest on the below issue?

```
Establishing connections ..... Done.
Checking registration information .....
Error updating registration information.  Details: Registration information
error.  Error type: 'ERROR_UNEXPECTED'.  Details:
javax.naming.directory.SchemaViolationException: [LDAP: error code 65 - Entry
cn=admin,cn=Administrators,cn=admin data violates the Directory Server schema
configuration because it includes attribute pwdChangedTime which is not
allowed by any of the objectclasses defined in that entry]; remaining name
'cn=admin,cn=Administrators,cn=admin data'
See /tmp/opends-replication-6304872164983350730.log for a detailed log of this
operation.
```

Answer (score 0):

Schema violation indicates that the entry is not compliant with the schema defined on the directory server.
Since the pwdChangedTime is by default defined in the Schema as an operational attribute and the error occurs with the dsreplication command (which is known to produce valid data), this probably indicates that you have messed up with the default schema and altered it in a non standard and incompatible way.